# move_past_bottom doesn't work in prawnpdf

Tags: ruby, prawn

I'm trying to force the cursor into the next column in Prawn, but can't seem to use move_past_bottom in a column box. What is another way to do this?

pdf.column_box([0, 640], :columns => 2, :width => pdf.bounds.width, :height => 620, :overflow => :truncate) do

This is basically the code:

```
        if pdf.cursor < 10
            pdf.move_past_bottom
        end
```

But it throws an error

Answer (score 2):

You were likely seeing the error:
`undefined method 'move_past_bottom' for #<Prawn::Document...`

The *move_past_bottom* method needs to be called on the *ColumnBox* object. Inside the `pdf.column_box(...) do ... end` block, this is available as the `pdf.bounds` object (the bounds reference changes when you nest into the ColumnBox).

This version of your code will work:

```
if pdf.cursor < 10
  pdf.bounds.move_past_bottom
end
```